# Why was apostrophe so vaguely used in Early Modern English?

Tags: english

So I have noticed in many of Shakespeare's poems that he used apostrophes in places where we don't usually see them now.

For Example: In the poem 'Fear No More' the first line is "Fear no more the heat ***o'*** the sun', why wasn't of used instead of o'? Also in another poem- "It is the star to every ***wand'ring*** bark".

So, Why were apostrophes used so vaguely in these Early Modern English poems?

Comment: Note that Shakespeare's language was not [Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English) (the language of Beowulf) but rather [Early Modern English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Modern_English).

Comment: Compare <of> /ɒv/ with <o'> /ə/

Comment: The pronunciation of English was changing around Shakespeare's time. He made use of this. He could choose between the pronunciations of the time by using apostrophes to distinguish how certain syllables were pronounced.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK That would make a good answer, if you want to add some examples.

Comment: Those apostrophes are hardly vague. They replace a letter, which is one of the uses apostrophes get put to. *Aren't, don't, isn't* are examples. Sometimes we shot-circuit words in this way, and it sticks. Sometimes, in verse, it makes the phrase flow better.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

(First, a note: this isn't Old English, but Early Modern English. Old English looks like this:

> Hƿæt. Ƿe Gardena in geardagum,
>   þeodcyninga, þrym gefrunon,
>   hu ða æþelingas ellen fremedon.

It's much older.)

Shakespeare's use of the apostrophe isn't vague or arbitrary: it's marking where certain letters shouldn't be pronounced.

For example, the word *wandering* can be pronounced with either two syllables ("wan-dring") or three ("wan-der-ing"). By replacing the E with an apostrophe, Shakespeare is telling the actor to use the two-syllable pronunciation. If you try it with the three-syllable pronunciation there, you'll see it messes up the iambic pentameter.

Comment: Notice the same still happens in music; I’ve seen it many times in hymns at Church.

Comment: Also, note that in the case of *wandr'ing*, a 2-syllable word was probably necessary to make the meter scan, rather than simply being a case of selecting one pronunciation over another. I'm less sure if *o'* scans differently than *of*.

Comment: @chepner: It doesn't but Heat o' the sun is an old fixed phrase.

Answer (score 28):

Shakespeare used apostrophes the exact same way we do—to signal that a sound is omitted.<sup>1</sup>

There's nothing vague about his usage. As [Draconis explains](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/30422/23611), "wand'ring" makes it clear that the vowel spelled by the missing "e" between "d" and "r" is to be omitted.<sup>2</sup> Usually, as here (but not with "o'" for "of"), this results in an entire syllable being dropped, which changes the scansion of the line, which is of course very important in metric verse.

In formal written English today, we mostly use apostrophes only in fixed contractions—e.g., "don't" for "do not" and "she's" for "she is". But they're used exactly the same way. "Don't" signals that the "o" sound in "not" (and therefore a whole syllable) is omitted.<sup>3</sup>

It may seem that there are so few of these contractions that we just learn each one as a separate word, and no longer have an "apostrophe rule". But a moment's reflection proves that can't be true. You can contract "is" or "has" onto almost any noun: "John's coming later", "The dog's got a bone", etc.

And, outside formal writing, people still use apostrophes in other locations, like writing "drinkin' and thinkin'" to signal the normal colloquial pronunciation instead of the one with a "g" at the end<sup>4</sup>—exactly as Shakespeare does with "o'". In every case, it works the same way for us as it did for Shakespeare.

In poetry (and sometimes song lyrics and other similar things) where scansion is important, people even still use apostrophes in exactly the same locations Shakespeare did. The only reason this doesn't come up in plays as often as in Shakespeare's day is that most plays aren't written to strict meter anymore.

There are a few cases that may seem strange, such as frequent "'d" for "ed" on the ends of words. What's going on there? Well, think of "I learned of a learned man"—the first "learned" is one syllable, the second is two.<sup>5</sup> This distinction was more widespread in Shakespeare's day, so many "-ed" forms that can only be monosyllabic to us were ambiguous to him. So he spelled them with "'d" to force the monosyllabic pronunciation, exactly as with "wand'ring".

---

<sub>1. There are, of course, other uses of the apostrophe—possessive "William's" doesn't omit anything, nor does the disambiguating plural marker in "p's and q's", nor do borrowed words that were spelled with apostrophes in their native language, except when that native language used apostrophes for omission. But that's also the same today.</sub>

<sub>2. Of course you need to know enough about English orthography and pronunciation to know how to omit the sound properly—in this case, that "wandering" can be pronounced as both "wan-dring" and "wan-der-ing", so the apostrophe tells you to select the former. But that's not unique to apostrophes; all English spelling works that way.</sub>

<sub>3. And again, the rest is up to your existing knowledge. In fact, notice how much more "don't" changes from "do not", compared to "wand'ring" from "wandering". Which one would you call more "vague"?</sub>

<sub>4. Of course there's not actually a /g/ sound at the end. But native English speakers *think* there's a /g/ sound at the end, so when you're writing plays, poems, lyrics, etc., using the apostrophe to signal a native speaker to "drop the g" (or just writing "eye dialect" in a novel), the signal works.</sub>

<sub>5. British spelling today usually distinguishes them as "learnt" vs. "learned", while a few generations ago they instead used "learned" vs. "learnèd". But Americans spell them indistinguishably, which makes for a better example here.</sub>

Comment: Possessive use doesn't omit anything, but it does originate in omission as the older *-es* genitive form started omitting the *e* to become *-s*. It did though change to be used even where there wouldn't have been an *e* in the earlier form. A clearer example is the Anglicisation of names like *Ó Raghallaigh* as *O'Reilly*.

Comment: @JonHanna Sure, diachronically it sort of signals an omission of -es, but even that isn't really accurate if you look at the way early printers used it (not to mention the plural "s'", adverbial genitives like "nowadays" that never had an apostrophe, etc.). Anyway, the same footnote already gives "p's and q's" and borrowed words as other examples, and anglicized names are effectively the same as borrowed words. Do you think any of that information needs to be added to the answer?

Comment: The [case of _shall not_ > _sha’n’t_ > _shan’t_](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-sha3.htm) might also be relevant.

Comment: @AlexShpilkin You mean because Shakespeare’s usage there was actually less vague than ours today? I suppose, but I don’t know that the extra complexity is worth getting into here. Do you think it’s needed? If so, do I also need to mention “won’t”, where we don’t just slide the “ll”, but also replace the “i” with an “o” making it even harder to reconstruct what’s going on?

Comment: There is no hard "g" in "-ing". Hard "g" is [ɡ], the default sound of "n" is [n], and the default sound of "ng" is [ŋ], not [nɡ]. E.g. "sing" is pronounced /sɪŋ/, not /sɪnɡ/ ("sin"+"g"). [ŋ] is a [velar nasal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velar_nasal). [ɡ] is a [voiced velar stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_velar_stop).

Comment: @CJDennis I'm trying to explain it in terms of what English speakers actually _think_ they're pronouncing, not what they actually _are_ pronouncing, since we're talking about apostrophes as cues from writers to actors, singers, etc. here. Is it too misleading without further explanation?

Comment: In the case of _-in'_, the apostrophe marks an **omitted** letter in writing, but a sound **change** in speech. Since apostrophes are purely orthographic and are not themselves pronounced, but do usually indicate a sound **omission**, perhaps you could clarify this? Even just removing the word "hard" would improve it, since "hard" relates to the pronunciation, not the spelling. Alternatively, you could say the spelling with the apostrophe indicates a change in the pronunciation from "ng" to "n".

Comment: @CJDennis I added a footnote, because I don't think there's a way to get it across any more concisely without adding more inaccuracy. Because I think it's important to the function of the apostrophe that English speakers think of what they're doing as "dropping the g sound".

Comment: And all that before we get onto the oft-used 'possessive apostrophe' as in **it's**. Which is wrong! Read 'Eats, Shoots and Leaves'.

Comment: If `-in'` is too contentious an example (It really isn't.) then there are always `'ve`, `'phone`, `mic'`, `'plane`, `'cello`, `'flu`, `Hallowe'en`,  `Jo'burg`, `fo'c'sle`, and `'95`.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP Some of those are already covered—`'95` is the same as `p's`, and `'ve` is complicated as slightly misleading like`n't`. And many of the rest are usually spelled without apostrophes, because they're more abbreviations than contractions. But do you think anything needs to be added in the first place, or is the answer sufficient as is?

Comment: @Tim Of course "it's" is only wrong for silly historical reasons. IIRC: "it's" had been used as eye-dialect spelling for funny laborer characters, who dropped the "h" and preserved the "t" from the standard Middle English "his" possessive of "hit". So, even when the upper crust started pronouncing the words the same way as the commoners, 18th century pedants didn't want to spell them the same way.

Comment: @abarnert  - 'his' and 'hers' also come under the same banner as 'its'.

Comment: @Tim Sort of. But nobody mistakenly writes `hi's` or `her's` to annoy you the way they do `it's`. And diachronically, they're very different. `its` was formed by adding the possessive `'s` to the new pronoun `it`, so by logic it _should_ have an apostrophe, as it once did. But `his` and `her` are survivals of the Old English genitive pronouns. And `hers` comes from the plural of `her`, not some kind of double-genitive. Anyway, synchronically, what is there to say that's relevant to the question? Just that these words don't have any "missing sounds", and don't have any apostrophes?

Comment: @abarnert - thanks for the explicit explanation! Can't see why hers should come from the plural - 'the husband is hers'...'Theirs may make more sense, but that's another issue! The 'it's bit is mainly because when I started teaching (many years ago, I did a lesson explaining the possessive apostrophe s in 'it's', totally wrongly), and I've been trying to make amends ever since. And no-one picked me up on it being wrong!!

Comment: @Tim Well, if your "many years ago" had been a few hundred more years ago than that, you would have been right instead of wrong. :) The history on this stuff is crazy, but pronouns are crazy in most languages, nouned genitive forms are also often crazy, and English is usually crazy, so… the rules make no sense synchronically, and even when you work out the diachronic reasons, they're not "reasons" in the sense of changes that a rational actor would make by applying logic.

Comment: @Tim But as for plural "hers", I think I was reporting a minority theory there. It's not clear why "heren->hers" happened at a different time from the other "-en" forms like "theiren->theirs", but that doesn't mean it wasn't the same reason (analogy with "his", which looks and sounds like it has -s even though it has -0).

Answer (score -2):

Shakespeare used the apostrophes for actors to not pronounce the left out letters so it would resemble spoken language of the time.

Actors reading it would know what to leave out, possibly also to show or help them express social class through informal speech or make the plays more accessible to the audience.

On 1 the possessive seems to omit ‘hi’ in William’s from ‘William his’ or in the female case ‘her’ from ‘Anna hers’ to Anna’s.

On 4 learned does not use an apostrophe there. It is an accent grave, not pronounced in English which would change the meaning to something ridiculous.

Comment: While this is absolutely correct, mind elaborating a little bit more? For example, you could relate this to modern use of apostrophes ("can't" for "cannot"), or explain why leaving out those sounds was important.

Comment: Your points 1-4 seem to be a comment on @abamert's answer, not an answer to the OP.

Comment: The possessive *'s* isn't short for *his* or *hers* -- it's just the genitive case ending.

Comment: @TKR While absolutely true, perhaps more to the point is that it was *never* short for *his* or *hers*. The final *-s* in those forms does come from the same Proto-Germanic ending, but the construction is *William-s* and *hi-s*, not *_William-[hi]s_.

Comment: @TKR While it's true that "s" isn't short for "his" or "hers" and never was, in Shakespeare's time, there was actually a sort of fad for using "his/is/ys" as a genitive (see Ben Jonson's play "Sejanus His Fall"), sometimes even on females or plurals ("Margere ys dowghter"). And as I understand it, there's some indication that many people mistakenly believed the "'s" genitive was abbreviating the "his" genitive despite "'s" being significantly older.

Comment: "learnèd" uses an accent grave to mark that the "e" should be pronounced; "learn'd" uses an apostrophe to mark that the "e" should _not_ be pronounced. These are obviously not the same thing. And neither one changes the meaning to something ridiculous. (I'm not sure what ridiculous meaning you were even implying here.) And both can be found in printed, professional writing.

Comment: An accent from the grave was the pun I intended.

Comment: @abarnert Yes, I've always assumed that was a folk etymology based on the (near-)homophony with nouns in *-s* (*Sejanus his = Sejanus's*).

Comment: @TKR Yeah, IIRC, Samuel Johnson even discusses the myth that “‘s” abbreviates “his”. Although I think he doesn’t say the his genitive is wrong, just that it’s different from the s genitive, and can only be used to intensify the sense of possession, and only with proper names, or something like that? The one good thing about the Daily Mail, Strunk & White, etc. is that future linguists will have a much easier time learning exactly what mistakes 20th century pedants made in analyzing the language. :)

Comment: @TKR - we often take it a stage further with names ending in s - *Sejanus', James', Jesus' - to denote possessive.

Comment: @Tim The rule _used_ to be that you only do this for "classical" names, so you have Achimedes' and Jesus', but Chris's and Dickens's. But even pedants stopped learning that rule nearly a century ago, so now nobody knows when you're supposed to use which one. Many style guides say to only use a bare apostrophe when the pronunciation is nil—so /dɪkɪnz/ is spelled "Dickens'", but /dɪkɪnzɪz/ is spelled "Dickens's"—but that assumes people consistently uee one pronunciation or the other, which isn't true.

Comment: @Tim People _do_ have some kind of rule that makes then tend to use nil more with some names than others, but AFAIK nobody's sure what it is. (Plus, "Jesus'" is one of the few that people are consistent with—but it's never nil, so modern style guides tell you the opposite of old ones.)